# Why AMP show me error in search console to google

Tags: wordpress, plugins, amp-html, google-search-console, asynchronous-messaging-protocol

thanks for you time..

Im here cause I need your help.

Im using AMP plugin and always Im seeing same error at search console

Only “style” tags with “amp-boilerplate” and “amp-custom” are allowed, and they can only be placed in the document header."

I dont understand how can I fix this issue if only Im using AMP plugin from frontend and I dont developing nothing manualy o custom

I tried to understand script and functions about AMP plugin that Im using called AMP TO AMP Project Contributors and I saw if there something I can do from plugin's frontend

Comment: Inspect the HTML source of your AMP pages. Look for <style> tags and check their content. Ensure that there is only one <style> tag in the document head, and it includes "amp-boilerplate" and "amp-custom". Remove any additional or conflicting styles. Also, you can use AMP validation tool provided by Google ([https://validator.ampproject.org/](https://validator.ampproject.org/)) and input the URL of your problematic AMP page. The tool will highlight specific errors and warnings.